# Connect to my other Macbook Pro not over LAN

Tags: network, wifi, screen-sharing

I can connect to my other Macbook Pro (both on OS High Sierra) using the built-in “Screen Sharing” app when at home, but I can't connect when I'm away from home and not on the same Wi-Fi.

I get an “Unable to resolve” error message which says the following: “Verify the name you entered and make sure your network connecting is working.”

Any idea how to make the “Screen Sharing” app work for when I'm out of the house and on a different WiFi network? Thanks!

Comment: I'm so tempted to say "Give up now & get TeamViewer". Punching in through a firewall is hard. Back to my Mac is gone, so there's no simple way to achieve this.

Comment: Yah, may not be worth the hassle. you have to set up your router to forward the correct ports to the Mac on your internal network. Not a lot of fun. Not to mention that you have now opened a hole in your router to the internet, all of it. Really, something like LogMeIn (there are many others) is your safest bet.